# why does bash respond with garbage characters and "command not found" when attempting to source a script?

Tags: bash, macos

I cannot source scripts on OS X 10.12.6 and I don't know why. Witness:

```
$type source
source is a shell builtin
$echo echo hi>x
$chmod +x x
$cat x
echo hi
$./x
hi
$source x
-bash: ����: command not found
```

it does seem to matter how I create file x or what commands it contains.
And "$. x" gives the same result.

(Because of how I use environment variables I don't want to make my scripts executable or otherwise fudge them up.)

***Update***: I found this happens for any script with the same name as an executable on the path or a shell built-in. But the error behavior varies from the message above (for x) to just killing bash outright (brew).

Now this is academic, but I'd like to understand this behaviour of the source build-in.  Thanks.

Comment: Note: always good to check the file is non-empty before you source, e.g. `[ -s "filename" ] && . ./filename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. source is searching the path and thus I am trying to source in binaries.  hence the garbage characters and random behaviors.

TIL source searched the path. Did not expect that.

Comment: From the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_002e): "If `filename` does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable is used to find `filename`."

Comment: Yes, if there is no slash (/) in the file name then the path is searched, the same as when the shell has to locate a command.  Under some circumstances, bash will fall back to checking the working directory if the path search fails, which differs from POSIX specifications.  FWIW, this is all documented in the Bash manual, and `man source` should turn up the relevant man page.